# how to execute two query's alongside each other?

Tags: mysql

i am trying to execute multiple query's at once / or one after the other but it's failing. why is this, here's how i've structured my code:

```
$query="
INSERT INTO ptb_users (user_id,
id,
first_name,
last_name,
email )
VALUES('NULL',
'NULL',
'".$firstname."',
'".$lastname."',
'".$email."'
)";
mysql_query($query) or die();
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET user_id=id");

$query="INSERT INTO ptb_profiles (id,
user_id,
display_name )
VALUES('NULL',
'NULL',
'".$username."'
)";
mysql_query($query) or die();
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_profiles SET id=user_id");
```

Comment: what is error message you have got?

Comment: im not getting any error

Answer (score 0):

You should really use PDO and prepared statements, mysql_* is no longer supported. It will make your life easier especially for repeating statements.

Otherwise, what is your error?

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Even if your answer really does not answer his question - it is sound advice not to use an obsolete interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use different name for variable `$query` and `$result`

it should be

```
$query="INSERT INTO ptb_users (user_id,id,first_name,last_name,email )VALUES('NULL','NULL','".$firstname."','".$lastname."','".$email."')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die();
$result1 = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET user_id=id");

$query2="INSERT INTO ptb_profiles (id,user_id,display_name )VALUES('NULL','NULL','".$username."')";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die();
$result3 = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_profiles SET id=user_id");
```

Comment: That should not affect if the queries succeed or not - only wether he retains any usable information about previous queries.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert `'NULL'` in fields which I'm guessing are auto_increment columns.
You should omit them from the query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ptb_users (first_name, last_name, email )
            VALUES('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."')";
```

Even if the null should be there, according to your implementation/definition of the tables, they should not be enclosed in `'` as that means the string NULL, not the value.